# Using Certbot i have difficulties with seperate certificates for multiple domains

Tags: certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

my problem is, if i run certbot multiple times for multiple domains, only the last domain (certificate request) seems to be operational.

1. certbot certonly --standalone --rsa-key-size 4096 -d example1.com
2. certbot certonly --standalone --rsa-key-size 4096 -d example2.com

Also the files i.e. /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.com are overwritten by /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.com. I would expect to have two folders in /etc/letsencrypt/live/ one for example1.com and one for example2.com.

My expectation would be, that both certificates (and their files unter /etc/letsencrypt/live/) could exist parallel.

Before trying this, i used a single certificete for the multiple domains with all domains listed after -d option. 
certbot certonly --standalone --rsa-key-size 4096 -d example1.com -d example2.com

This worked perfect, but does not fit my needs. I need a single certificate per domain.

I appreciate your help and hope i could make my point clear.

I am Using Ubuntu 18.04 and certbot 0.27.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was deninitly on my side ... i was using a selfmade script and was overlooking that at the beginnig i was deleting the whole /etc/letsencrypt directory.

After removing this delete command everything worked as expected.